# AngularJS slide out menu

Tags: css, angularjs

I am trying to create a slide out menu to no avail. I want the text (home,users) to show up upon clicking the >> button. I have run out of ideas and I am sure I am missing something very obvious. Also, this is my first crack at animations in AngularJS.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Q8UF1mPCpTAVDn59D1wV?p=preview

Comment: try upgrading your angular js version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you haven't included `angular-animate.js` which is required for working with animations in Angular. Second, you're using the `.ng-enter`/`.ng-leave` classes which isn't used for `ng-show`. You should be using `.ng-hide`/`.ng-show` classes instead. There's an example at the bottom of this page that should get you going: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow